# Edit XML tag by attribute

Tags: vb.net

I have a XML document which looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
    <Data key="dailyKey">19283</Data>
</Configuration>
```

And in my vb.net program I want to change the value from "`<Data>`" by the attribute "dailyKey"

I have tried to understand myself on this but cannot figure out how to edit TAG by ATTRIBUTE

Please help, Richard

Comment: vb.net or php? im confused

Comment: vb.net sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use XPath expressions and the `SelectSingleNode` method like this:

```
Dim node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//data[@key=""dailyKey""]")
```

Then you can modify the value of `node` as you wish to. You can find more XPath examples at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx).

The workflow in its entirety would be:

#### 1. Load the XML Document for manipulation

You can use the `XmlDocument` class to load (and subsequently save) your XML Document like this:

```
Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
xmlDoc.Load("<Here goes your url // You can also feed in a stream to this method>")
```

#### 2. Locate the node you want to modify

As mentioned earlier, use the `SelectSingleNode` function to locate the node you are trying to modify the value of. It takes an XPath expression.

```
Dim node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//data[@key=""dailyKey""]")
```

#### 3. Modify the node

You can now edit the node (tag) in whatever way you wish. It seems you want to edit the contained value. Do it by changing the `Value` property of the `XmlNode`:

```
node.Value = 224062 'Random value. Change to suit your needs.
```

#### 4. Save the XML Document (Obviously :P)

```
xmlDoc.Save()
```

Comment: Thanks, now I have everything I need to have infinite Adobe licenses with auto updates, no cracked version! Thank you very much

Comment: dear Fᴀʀʜᴀɴ Aɴᴀᴍ  If my XML file is like this, what will the code look like?
```<Setting value="23,252" key="melocation"/>```

Comment: @vahidAraghi Use something like `Dim node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//data[@key=""melocation""]")`. You can access `node.Value` to retrieve the coordinates(?).

Comment: But when I try to set the value, I get this message:   

```Cannot set a value on node type 'Element```

Comment: @vahidAraghi https://stackoverflow.com/a/6651126/4546874. This might help.

Comment: Fᴀʀʜᴀɴ Aɴᴀᴍ Dear Fᴀʀʜᴀɴ Aɴᴀᴍ Thank you for helping me.